# Kotlin - forEach

Tags: kotlin

I am beginner in Kotlin.
How do you explain the following code snippet ?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var k = listOf<Double>(1.2,77.8,6.3,988.88,0.1)

        k.forEach(::println)
}
```

This runs fine and gives the list but can someone please help with the explanation for how does k.forEach(::println) really work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) takes each element in `k` and does *what* you specify it to do. In your example, the "*what*" argument is `::println`, which refers to the stdlib function [`println(message: Any)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html). The `::` introduced a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to this function. Each element is passed as the argument `message` to `println` and thus it's being printed on the console.

To make it more clear, you could pass a lambda instead of the function reference like this:

```
k.forEach{
   println(it)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[inline fun  Iterable.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit)](http://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1478)

> public inline fun  Iterable.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
>       for (element in this) action(element) }